# Web Scraping ETFs Daily Data VBA

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, yahoo-finance

I'm trying to web scrape some daily info of differents ETFs. I found that https://www.marketwatch.com/ have a accurate info.
The most relevant info is the open Price, outstanding shares, NAV, total assets of the ETF.
Here is the link for IVV US Equity: https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/fund/ivv

I have web scraped with VBA before but the HTML of the pages I had used are different, I don't know if this is because some values of the ETFs (such as Price and Taded Volume) change constantly.
The idea is to create a code to extract relevant info and create a data base to analyze Macroeconomics factor using the ETFs as market indicators of flows between countries, regions, etc...

Mi first approach would be with VBA but after I get more into the data I would like to try with Python (after I get more conffident with it) to automate the webscraping process on a daily basis.

I am open to any suggestion or any other website that could be useful (I have tried with Yahoo Finance and Morningstar and I get the same problema with the HTML code).

This is my poor code:

```
Sub Get_Data()
    
    Dim ticker As String, enlace As String
    
    ticker = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ETFs").Cells(2, 2).Value 'IVV
    'link = "https://www.morningstar.com/etfs/arcx/" & ticker & "/quote.html"
    'link = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" & ticker & "?p=" & ticker
    link = "https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/fund/" & ticker
        
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        
    Dim x As Integer
    x = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ETFs").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    'Dim i As Integer
    'For i = 2 To x
    
    Dim total_net_assets As Variant, open_price As Variant, NAV As Variant, shares_out
            
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
    With ie
        .Visible = False
        .navigate link
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
            Do
                DoEvents
                On Error Resume Next
                ' Here is where I get the problem of not knowing how to reference the values I need because the class name appears repeatedly
                total_net_assets = .document.getElementsByClassName("").Value
                open_price = .document.getElementByClassName("price").Value
                NAV = .document.getElementByClassName("").Value
                shares_out = .document.getElementByClassName("kv__value kv__primary ").Value
                On Error GoTo 0
            Loop
    End With
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ETFs").Cells(2, 13).Value = total_net_assets
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ETFs").Cells(2, 14).Value = NAV
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ETFs").Cells(2, 15).Value = open_price
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ETFs").Cells(2, 16).Value = shares_out
    ie.Quit
    'Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: I can't get de NAV, Price, Outstanding Shares and Total Assets. Basically I don't know hoy to get the element because the class name appears several time through the code. I can't "reference" the values.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Try the script that QHarr suggested @Nico Rodriguez. That should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Access method:**

I use [XMLHTTP](https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/) requests as much faster than opening IE.

**Code notes:**

The following reads in fund short codes from Sheet1 column A, starting in `A2`, into an array. You can easily extend this adding more funds into column A.

This array is looped issuing XMLHTTP requests by concatenating the fund code into the `BASE_URL` variable.

I use a class, `clsHTTP`, to hold the XMLHTTP object to be efficient - no need to keep creating and destroying the object.

I provide this class with two methods. One to retrieve the target page innerHTML (`GetString`), and the other to extract the required info if available (`GetInfo`). I use a dictionary to test if the searched for labels are present. If present I grab the associated value. If not, I have a placeholder `vbNullString` in the dictionary.

I add each scraped result into a collection called `results`. At the end I loop this writing out to the sheet. By keeping most of the work in memory this provides for much faster scraping.

---

**Retrieving info from HTML:**

The `labels` e.g. `Open`, and `values` come in pairs.

You can generate a `nodeList` (think collection as with `getElementsByClassName`)  by using `querySelectorAll` method to apply a [class CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) to gather the label elements by their class name `kv__label`. The `"."` is the class selector.

```
Set labels = .querySelectorAll(".kv__label") '<== nodeList of labels
```

You do the same to get the associated values:

```
Set values = .querySelectorAll(".kv__value.kv__primary") '<== nodeList of associated values. Same length as labels nodeList so can use same index to retrieve associated label/value pairs from each nodeList.
```

You loop the labels using the dictionary in the `clsHTTP` method `.GetInfo` to see if you searched for labels are present, if they are, the associated value is retrieved from values by using the same index as where the label was found in the `nodeList` `labels`, and the dictionary `vbNullString` value for that label is updated with the actual retrieved value, else it is left as `vbNullString`.

---

### Sample results:

### [image]

### VBA:

**Class module clsHTTP:**

```
Option Explicit
Private http As Object

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
End Sub

Public Function GetString(ByVal url As String) As String
    Dim sResponse As String
    With http
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
        .send
        sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
        GetString = sResponse
    End With
End Function

Public Function GetInfo(ByVal html As HTMLDocument) As Object
    Dim dict As Object, i As Long
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.Add "Open", vbNullString
    dict.Add "Shares Outstanding", vbNullString
    dict.Add "Total Net Assets", vbNullString
    dict.Add "NAV", vbNullString

    Dim values As Object, labels As Object

    With html
        Set values = .querySelectorAll(".kv__value.kv__primary")
        Set labels = .querySelectorAll(".kv__label")

        For i = 0 To labels.Length - 1
            If dict.Exists(labels.item(i).innerText) Then dict(labels.item(i).innerText) = values.item(i).innerText
        Next
    End With
    Set GetInfo = dict
End Function
```

**Standard module 1:**

```
Option Explicit   
Public Sub GetFundInfo()
    Dim sResponse As String, html As HTMLDocument, http As clsHTTP, i As Long
    Dim headers(), funds(), url As String, results As Collection, ws As Worksheet
    Const BASE_URL As String = "https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/fund/"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    headers = Array("Open", "Shares Outstanding", "Total Net Assets", "NAV")
    Set results = New Collection
    Set http = New clsHTTP
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set html = New HTMLDocument

    funds = Application.Transpose(ws.Range("A2:A3").Value) '<== Change the range here to the single column range containing your dotNums.

    For i = LBound(funds) To UBound(funds)
        If Not IsEmpty(funds(i)) Then
            url = BASE_URL & funds(i)
            html.body.innerHTML = http.GetString(url)
            results.Add http.GetInfo(html).Items
        End If
    Next

    If results.Count > 0 Then
        Dim item As Variant, r As Long, c As Long
        r = 2: c = 2
        With ws
            .Cells(1, c).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
            For Each item In results
                .Cells(r, c).Resize(1, UBound(item) + 1) = item
                r = r + 1
            Next
        End With
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

**Set-up:**

[image]

---

Without using a class:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetFundInfo()
    Dim sResponse As String, html As HTMLDocument,  i As Long
    Dim headers(), funds(), url As String, results As Collection, ws As Worksheet
    Const BASE_URL As String = "https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/fund/"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    headers = Array("Open", "Shares Outstanding", "Total Net Assets", "NAV")
    Set results = New Collection
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set html = New HTMLDocument

    funds = Application.Transpose(ws.Range("A2:A3").Value) '<== Change the range here to the single column range containing your dotNums.

    For i = LBound(funds) To UBound(funds)
        If Not IsEmpty(funds(i)) Then
            url = BASE_URL & funds(i)
            html.body.innerHTML = GetString(url)
            results.Add GetInfo(html).Items
        End If
    Next

    If results.Count > 0 Then
        Dim item As Variant, r As Long, c As Long
        r = 2: c = 2
        With ws
            .Cells(1, c).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
            For Each item In results
                .Cells(r, c).Resize(1, UBound(item) + 1) = item
                r = r + 1
            Next
        End With
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


Public Function GetString(ByVal url As String) As String
    Dim http As Object
    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Dim sResponse As String
    With http
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
        .send
        sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
        GetString = sResponse
    End With
End Function

Public Function GetInfo(ByVal html As HTMLDocument) As Object
    Dim dict As Object, i As Long
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.Add "Open", vbNullString
    dict.Add "Shares Outstanding", vbNullString
    dict.Add "Total Net Assets", vbNullString
    dict.Add "NAV", vbNullString

    Dim values As Object, labels As Object

    With html
        Set values = .querySelectorAll(".kv__value.kv__primary")
        Set labels = .querySelectorAll(".kv__label")

        For i = 0 To labels.Length - 1
            If dict.Exists(labels.item(i).innerText) Then dict(labels.item(i).innerText) = values.item(i).innerText
        Next
    End With
    Set GetInfo = dict
End Function
```

Comment: NICE! As always, providing excelent and complete answers. Thank you, I will give it a try and come back to you.

Comment: No worries. Any problems let me know.

Comment: Sorry QHarr, I'm having a compilation error with the GetInfo function. It appears a message that the type hasn't being defined. How can I fix this??
Maybe the code is too PRO for my coding skills, and I'm implementing it the wrong way :(.

Comment: Have you added a reference to Microsoft HTML Object Library? VBE > Tools > References.

Comment: It keeps throwing a compilation error at "http As clsHTTP", I don't know if I have to add another reference

Comment: I can't access the link :(

Comment: I still can't acces the link, but is because the internet I am connected to blocked them.

Comment: Yes! I did, are there any other modules I have to name?
I mean, with the functions is the same?

Comment: No. It you put the code for clsHTTP in a class module named clsHTTP, and the other code in a standard module and use the code exactly as shown it should work fine. Did you include the Dim http As clsHTTP - as shown in code?

Comment: Sorry for the ignorance, I will give a try now.

Comment: See the latest edit. I have added a version that doesn't use a class object.

Comment: I finally understood the class module hahaha, it Works perfectly. Thanks QHarr!!
Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Yessssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss :-) It is a more efficient way to write code, in this case, in this way and you can easily re-use the class and adapt its methods as required.

Comment: Any further problems let me know and remember to accept an answer at some point if situ solved.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so you will need to create two loops. You can just keep reusing the `elem0`, `elem1`, and `elemColl(1)` variables for each price point you need - just make sure to reset `bFoundIt` to False for each new iteration so you do not exit the For Loops early.

For your `total_net_assets` var, you will first **loop the class of `kv__item`**. You will then need to loop each class collection of `kv__label` within the `kv__item`'s elements and stop when you match the innerText: **Total Net Assets**. Once you match this, you will use the first coll obj `elem0` to get the `kv__value kv__primary` class name for it.

```
Dim IE As Object, elem0 As Object, elem1 As Object, i As Long, bFoundIt As Boolean

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
With IE
    .Visible = False
    .navigate link
    While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        DoEvents
        bFoundIt = False
        For Each elem0 In .document.getElementsByClassName("kv__item")
            For Each elem1 In elem0.getElementsByClassName("kv__label")
                If elem1.innerText = "Total Net Assets" Then
                    bFoundIt = True
                    total_net_assets = elem0.getElementsByClassName("kv__value kv__primary ")(0).innerText
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next elem1
            If bFoundIt Then Exit For
        Next elem0
```

Comment: Perfect! I understood the logic. Thanks.
I just tried the code but nothing happen, it just keeps running. 
Do you think I should try with Python?

Comment: Oops you can get rid of the `Do...Loop` that you had in your original code. I updated mine to remove the `Do` that was showing.

Comment: Excelent! Now it Works perfectly. Thank you.